# Trying to find the height of a div in Vue.js, I'm accessing it through refs gives error

Tags: vue.js, height

I am trying to find the height of div in Vuejs,

```
let height = this.$refs.infoBox.clientHeight()+'px';
```

it gives me an error saying that I cannot find the client height of `null` / `undefined`.

Comment: Please take the time to format your question title in proper english without typo.

Answer (score 3):

If your div have a reference attach to it like: `<div ref="infoBox" />` you can access the height of that div with `this.$refs.infoBox.offsetHeight`.

**NOTE**: You can access the height of the div only **after** the component has been mounted. This won't work:

```js
{
  // ...

  created() {
    // WARNING
    // Will trigger an error because the DOM is not mounted at this point.
    console.log(this.$refs.infoBox.offsetHeight);
  },

  // ...
}
```

Comment: u mean it should only be accessible in created hook ,after componnet is mounted ? but you nare also saying it will trigger error ?

Comment: As stated above, `$refs` is only accessible **after** your component has been mounted. If you try to access `$refs` _before_ the component is mounted, then it will trigger an error.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto @geauser's example, if you would like to access a reference after the component is mounted use the mounted hook:

```
{
  // ...

  mounted() {
    // DOM *is* mounted at this point.
    console.log(this.$refs.infoBox.offsetHeight);
  },

  // ...
}
```

[Vue lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html).